# Any diagram or method can help better understand and construct recursive method?

Tags: recursion

I think it is hard to get a whole picture in mind about how it works. I read several recursion method, and I get lost after a little bit recursion. That is why I ask how you guy understand a recursive method. Is there any analysis method to help with that, like diagram or something?

For example, as below, the simple binary search example has many conditions, and it is hard to imagine how it goes after several steps of recursion.

```
public class FindIndexBS<Item extends Comparable<Item>> {
    private Item[] arr;

    public FindIndexBS(Object[] arr) {
        this.arr = (Item[]) arr;
    }

    public int solve(Item item) {
        int lo = 0, hi = arr.length - 1;
        return solve(lo, hi, item);
    }

    private Integer solve(int lo, int hi, Item item) {
        if (lo > hi) return -1;
        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        int cpm = item.compareTo(arr[mid]);

        if (cpm < 0) return solve(lo, mid - 1, item);
        else if (cpm > 0) return solve(mid + 1, hi, item);
        else return mid;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = i * 1;
        }
        FindIndexBS<Integer> bs = new FindIndexBS<Integer>(arr);
        System.out.println("index of the number is: " + bs.solve(40));
    }
}
```

Adarsh Bhat's method is a good visualization of how it goes. But I don't know how to apply that method to more complicated method like the Binary Search.

Comment: There is a great explanation [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start off with the definition of Recursion:

> Recursion is the process of defining something in terms of itself. As
>   it relates to java programming, recursion is the attribute that allows
>   a method to call itself. A method that calls itself is said to be
>   recursive.

Now lets take an example of a recursive method such as "To Find the Factorial of a number":

```
int fact(int n)
{
    int result;

   if(n==1)
     return 1;

   result = fact(n-1) * n;
   return result;
}
```

when we use recursion a concept of a stack comes into play which pops out the data once the operation reaches a constant.

Here let us say we pass a number 5:

### fact(2)=fact(1) * 2

### fact(3)=fact(2) * 3

### fact(4)=fact(3) * 4

### fact(5)=fact(4) * 5    <---------- This where your method gets called first.

This is what s in your stack. Since `fact(1)` value is 1. it starts computing and after each computation it pops that entry and feeds it to the next equation below it.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: It is a good visualization, and helpful for understanding . But when it has more conditions, I still cannot imagine it. Can you look at my updates and give me more ideas if possible.   Thanks

Comment: There is no imagination involved here. All you gotta do is sit down with a pen an paper and trace the program with some constant data. This is how  you will be able to learn recursive functions. What i have told here is just to get your imagination going. The rest is up to you. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is not really language related, it is the same concept in all languages. It just means "calling itself".
An example in Java:

```
public int getNumber(int low){
  low += 5;
  if ( low < 100 ){
    return getNumber(low); // REC
    }
   return low;
}
```

The line where I added the REC comment, is a line where the method actually calls itself (which is recursion).

Comment: I just think it is hard to get a whole picture in mind about how it works. I read several recursion method, and I get lost after a little bit recursion. That is why I ask how you guy understand a recursive method.

Comment: A recursive method is "a method that calls itself". That's about all there is to say about it.